# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, twitter-bootstrap, controller

I'm trying to implement a Twitter Boostrap login form, that's gonna be used on every page (because the navigation bar is a part of the layout).

However, when trying the code below I get the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
```

**User controller:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    ...
  end

  def login
    ...
  end

end
```

**_navigation.html.erb:**

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
    <%= form_for("user", :url => user_path) do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :email%>
        <%= f.text_field(:email, :size => 30, :class => 'login_field', :placeholder => 'Användarnamn')%>
        <%= f.label :password%>
        <%= f.text_field(:password, :size => 30, :class => 'login_field', :placeholder => 'Lösenord')%>

        <%= f.submit "Logga in", :class => 'login_submit btn btn-primary' %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**config/routes.rb:**

```
get "home/index"

resources :users
resources :projects
resources :tickets

root :to => 'home#index'
```

**rake routes (that has to do with users):**

```
    users GET    /users(.:format)             users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)             users#create
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)         users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)    users#edit
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)         users#show
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)         users#update
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)         users#destroy
```

I'm new to Rails but find it strange that it complains that the route doesn't exist because the action "show" is to be found inside the user controller.

The other thing I'm wondering about is why it looks for the action "show", while it should be "login" in this case?

Why is this happening and what shall I do?

Comment: What does your `config/routes.rb` file look like?

Comment: Can you do `rake routes` in your console and check what is the path for login action of users controller. It should be something like `login_users_path` if the login is a collection action for users resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your error is in this line

```
<%= form_for("user", :url => user_path) do |f| %>
```

`user_path` is expecting an id.  if you change that to `users_path`, that should fix it but I don't think that's your intention.

UPDATE: to use the `login` action on the users controller, you need to update your routes

```
resources :users do
  post :login, on: :collection, as: :login
end
```

passing the `:as` option creates a named_route for you called `login_users_path` which you can use on your `form_for`. and since we wanted to do a post, we also need to specify that in the `form_for`

```
<%= form_for("user", :url => login_users_path, :html => { :method => :post }) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried the code but get the following error: "undefined local variable or method `login_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f8556a37c98>:0x007f8556f3a1c8>"

Comment: sorry that should be `login_users_path`, forgot that it's under a resource

Answer (score 2):

Update your routes.rb to look like:

```
get "home/index"

resources :users do
  post :login, :on => :collection
end

resources :projects
resources :tickets

root :to => 'home#index'
```

and in your view file change the form_for line to be:

```
<%= form_for("user", :url => login_users_path) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

`resources :users` only adds default routes. If you want to add new action (other then defaults) you need to use '`collection`. And you can specify the method `get` or `post`. After adding to `routes.rb`. You can get the `path` by running `rake routes` then you add the correct route in the `action` of form.

```
   resources :users, :collection => {:login => :post}
```